I want to create a plaque to apply to a complex curved surface defined by an imported STL

My STL import represents the surface and shape of where the plaque is to be applied. I would like to create an object (the plaque) using a rectangular mesh that can be applied to the object represented by the STL. I have a rectangular mesh of the complex surface using a boolean but now I need to be the right shape and thickness. Any suggestions for a best approach?


Could you explain what is in the provided picture "the object represented by the STL" ?

Yes, the object represented by the STL is the object on the left side shaped like a fish. I say it is represented by an STL since it is an object created from an STL file import.

So what I understand is that you are looking for (1) a thin plate of constant thickness (the "plaque") (2) of rectangular outline (3) with a hole in the middle with the shape of the "fish". This thin plate is not flat, but (4) should reproduce the curvature of the STL surface. If I am right, what are your expectation for the extrapolated curved surface ?

Close but to clarify. The thin plate (the plaque) will have the same outline shape as the fish, not rectangular, and, indeed has the same curvature of the STL surface. The final object I am looking for will look the same as object on the left except it will be a plaque applied to the object on the left. The difference is the plaque will have a rectangular grid mesh and will be easily manipulated with the blender tools (I will be adding embosses and such to the plaque). Think of the plaque as a veneer on an irregular surface (like a cap on a tooth).

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?



I made some progress by deleting all surfaces on the cube object I did not want and then extruding the fish shaped surface a thickness. Now I am stuck because I keep getting python errors when I try to export the STL for 3D printing.

Solution obtained. I deleted all of the unwanted surfaces on the cube and extruded the surface I wanted to create the plaque.
